# Cannot open c# winform project in another computer

Tags: c#, winforms

I build a win form application using visual studio 2015 and additionally I used openhardwaremonitor.dll  and circularprogressbar.dll. I compiled it successfully and run that application in my machine without any error but when I tried to run that in different computer It didn't open. When click on the exe file nothing happen. I looked at the task manager and when I open the exe file it comes to background process section and then dissapear. It doesnot open. I tried hardly by installing .net frameworks but nothing works

But I build a simple winform project with a button and label it works correctly on different computers but that one is not working

Can anyone help me to solve this please

Thank you

Comment: Did you copy the additional DLLs you mentioned to the second computer, or just the exe?

Comment: Are any exceptions in the event log, that belong to your program?

Comment: your 'question' doesn't have enough information to it.  It is likely as @Andy said; dll copy issue.. but you haven't specified whether you're publishing/installing the project, or simply running the executable from a bin folder on that machine.. or anything in that regard.

Comment: Making your program work on other machines is the other 90% of the project.  Delete try/catch from your code until you figured out how to actually recover from the exception.  And subscribing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is never optional.

Comment: All the additional dll files are in the bin/release folder I copied that full folder to another machine(both dlls ad exe file)

Comment: I made a setup file and install it on another computer still not running

Answer (score 2):

There's an add-on you can get that will assist in the construction of installation projects You should search for Visual Studio Installer Projects (at the time of writing available at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects if you're dealing with Visual Studio 2015). It might do a better job of helping you to detect and deliver the necessary files.

Answer (score 1):

if you use any custom .dll files(librarys, etc) that are not present on the other computer then the .exe file will not run. You need to copy those dll files and keep them in the same folder as the .exe file so the .exe file knows where to find them. if you compile the project and then just take all the contents from the bin folder it should run just fine.